# AJAX update or render "points" the correct clientId but does not update the value in datatable

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I'd like to update an `<h:outputText>` in one column by processing a value of an `<h:selectOneRadio>` located in another column inside a datatable:

```
...
            <rich:column>           
                    <h:selectOneRadio id="mainSelect" value="#{row.select1}"  required="true" > 
                        <f:selectItems value="#{row.responses}" var="resp" itemLabel="#{resp.label}" itemValue="#{resp.response}" />                                
                        <a4j:ajax event="change"    render="outputPanel1"
                                    listener="#{subTableView.updateSecond(row.select1)}"  />    
                    </h:selectOneRadio>
            </rich:column>
            <rich:column>
                <a4j:outputPanel id="outputPanel1">
                        <h:outputText value="#{row.select1}"/>
                        <p>#{component.clientId}</p>
               </a4j:outputPanel>
            </rich:column>
...
```

See below my datatable and Firebug's *HTML* panel below pointing (automatically highlighted in yellow by Firebug) the correct `clientId` when the radio button is clicked but the value taken from the database loaded at view build time inside the `<span>` does not change (from `YesR` to `NoR` in this example).

[image: datatable being updated]

The `NoR` value is attributed to the correct radio component as seen below but does not replace the `YesR`:

[image: changed values highlighted within Firebug]

The good thing is that each row's process is independent and the `selectOneRadio` process is pointing to the corresponding `outputPanel1` for each row. I tried different combinations of `<p:ajax update="">`, `<f:ajax render="">` and `<h:panelGroup>` without success. I also tried different events like `click`, `change` and `valueChange` without success.

What could be the reason that the value in the `outputPanel1` is not updated?

I am using WildFly 9.0.2 (Mojarra 2.2.12) with RichFaces 4.5.8 (or PF5.3) (tested on different browsers).

**EDIT (for onepotato):**

```
 <rich:dataTable    id="grid" width="5000"  
                                value="#{subTableView.getAllHeaders()}"
                                var="head" >

                <rich:column colspan="3" >
                    <h:outputText value="#{head.name}" />
                </rich:column>

                <rich:collapsibleSubTable   id="cellGrid"  value="#{head.questions}" var="row"  >

                    <rich:column>
                            <h:outputText value="#{row.question}" />
                    </rich:column>

                    <rich:column>           
                        <h:selectOneRadio id="mainSelect" value="#{row.select1}"  required="true" > 
                            <f:selectItems value="#{row.responses}" var="resp" itemLabel="#{resp.label}" itemValue="#{resp.response}" />                                
                            <a4j:ajax event="change"    render="outputPanel1"
                                        listener="#{subTableView.updateSecond(row.select1)}"  />    
                        </h:selectOneRadio>
                </rich:column>
                <rich:column>
                    <a4j:outputPanel id="outputPanel1">
                            <h:outputText value="#{row.select1}"/>
                            <p>#{component.clientId}</p>
                   </a4j:outputPanel>
                </rich:column>


                </rich:collapsibleSubTable>

            </rich:dataTable>
```

**Bean:**

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class SubTableView implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EJB
    private PublicService publicService;


    private List<Response> responses;
    private Response response = new Response();

    private List<Header> headers;
    private Header header = new Header();

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

        this.responses = publicService.getAllResponses();

        this.headers = publicService.getAllHeaders();
    }

+getters & setters
```

**Service:**

```
@PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;



   public List<Header> getAllHeaders(){

            List<Header> headers = entityManager.createQuery("select h from Header h",Header.class).getResultList();

                    for(Header h : m.getHeaders())
                    {

                       headers.add(h);


                           for(Question q : h.getQuestions())
                           {

                           }

                    }

            return headers; 

    }
```

Comment: What does the listener do? It should work without it.

Comment: Yes it works without it. (Contains a sysout check method)

Comment: I removed my answer as I realized that our cases are probably not the same. Looking at the code that you posted, it should work, even without the listener. Could you please provide the code for the bound table content and the managed bean so that I can reproduce it in my machine?

Comment: @onepotato: I edited the question. thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although tried several times before with PrimeFaces Datatable: PFS finally worked here (RF dataTable) for this:

I added the following ajax line in selectOneRadio: `<p:ajax update="@(.status)"  />`

with the target column:

```
              <h:panelGroup id="outputPanel1" styleClass="status">

                        <h:outputText id="display1" value="#{row.answer.select1}" />

              </h:panelGroup>
```

But now I have the following issue: [TabView First Tab not toggled as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34111487/tabview-first-tab-not-toggled-as-expected)

Comment: If this is your answer, please improveyour question (tags and content). It does not match at all

Comment: Could you explain why? Did you try to understand my problem?

Comment: Your solution uses a p:ajax but there is no PrimeFaces tag and nothing PrimeFaces related in the question

Comment: Ok i will add primefaces tag. Thanks.

Comment: If you don't improve the content of the question it will be removed since there is no indication of it being PrimeFaces related. So please also improve the content of the question

Comment: @Kukeltje: You also have `<p:ajax update="">` clearly written. My intend is to feed-back the community with helpful contents: I am sure it is the same for you.

Comment: I did read the question but just mentioning it does not state a relation or cause and very few people mix Richfaces and PrimeFaces so if your question is that 'blurry' it will not help people a lot, at least I would not have thought of providing a p:ajax solutioj for a richDatatable. And **you* stated p:ajax somewhere in the middle, not me…

Comment: Let people decide if it is helpful or not. As a person who struggled on this I think it is.

Comment: That is what I am doing. I'm not saying the problem behind the whole question/answer is totally useless, I'm saying it can be improved regarding clearity etc…  people using richfaces will probably move on if they see you need to add PrimeFaces and people using PrimeFaces will not read beyond the question if they encounter a richDatable…

Comment: OK: but this is the only "combined solution" I found so far for this specific problem. I just re-tried again in a PF dataTable and a PF subTable with the same PFS <p:ajax> solution but it does not respond. I would be also very happy to use only PF or only RF but this is the reality at least I observed. This was a real headache for me.